# SSH2 in Bitvise terminates unexpectedly

Tags: webserver, web-hosting, public-key, bitvise

I'm trying to connect Bitvise with a cloud server to make some changes in my magneto website.

When I click login it creates connection without any problem. But after a few seconds it terminates automatically.

I configured correctly username, password, port, host and also public key file in Host Key Manager.

Now I am getting this error:

> The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: Error class:
>   LocalSshDisconn, code: ConnectionLost, message: FlowSshTransport:
>   received EOF.

Do I need to configure any other things? I have no idea. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for weeks, but the following solved it for me:

I finally re-uploaded as recommended in:
https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download 
and the same message displayed:

> The SSH session has terminated with error, Reason: Error class; LocalSshDisconn, code: Connection Lost, message: FlowSshTransport: received EOF.

YET on the Bitvise SSH Client window there is a link named:
"Proxy Settings" I clicked it and haphazardly changed from "Use global proxy settings" to "use profile proxy settings".

GUESS WHAT ... it did work for me!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Bitvise, and it started to work when I chose *Elevation: Yes*, in the Authentication-section of the Login-tab.

With PuTTY I kept getting fatal errors. After trying the Elevated session with Bitvise, the PuTTY started to work again too, without any further changes.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: Error class: LocalSshDisconn, code: ConnectionLost

The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: Error in component session/transport/kexHandler. Error class: Flow

[Resolved Link](https://vvcares.com/blog/bitvise-connecting-error-localsshdisconn/)

bitvise authentication establishes a connection without difficulty. However, after a few seconds it automatically terminates.
Solution :

1. Make sure the bitvise version is above v7.42
2. choose Elevation: Yes, in the Authentication-section of the Login-tab dropdown.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).